# 403 Forbidden on php mkdir

Tags: php

I'm having a 403 Forbidden page when excecuting a php script with mkdir function.

here is the mkdir code:

```
mkdir('uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/', 777)
```

I have tried 775, 666 permissions, but nothing.
Insde the dir i want to store images, mp3's and videos.
Can anyone help me?

***UPDATE 1***

here is the whole script:

```
$folderStr = $_REQUEST['folderName'];

//create SEO firndly directory name
$upload_folder =    preg_replace("'\s+'", '-', $folderStr);

// The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).
$upload_path = 'uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/';

//Check whether folder exists or create with the name supplied
if(is_dir($upload_folder))
echo 'directory exists';
else
mkdir('uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/', 777);
```

It supposed to make a new directory into the folder "uploads" with the name given from the form which i get it from there with value 'folderName', and upload the files given from the form into the new dir which is created.
Also it can't write greek characters on the foldername. what i have to change to make it work?

Comment: The 403 would indicate that you don't have permission to access the script over the web, not that you don't have permission to create a directory

Comment: I'm running it locally on my computer.

Comment: We can't say without more details. Is the PHP script located in a directory where you have other scripts working already? Does it have file permissions that make it readable by the web server user?

Comment: In the same folder i have and other scripts and yes they work fine. How can give it permissions?

Comment: The easiest way to make your script work would probably be to assign the same group to $upload_folder and your webserver, and set permissions on $upload_folder to "group writable".

Answer (score 1):

You need a zero in front of the desired mode, e.g.

```
mkdir('uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/', 0777)
```

If you use '777', you will get strange permissions like this:

`dr----x--t`

instead of this:

`drwxrwxr-x`

**Reason (from [PHP chmod](http://php.net/chmod) docs):** "Note that mode is not automatically assumed to be an octal value, so to ensure the expected operation, you need to prefix mode with a zero (0)."

I can confirm that this still happens in PHP 7.0.3, despite related [changes to integer handling](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php): "Previously, octal literals that contained invalid numbers were silently truncated (0128 was taken as 012). Now, an invalid octal literal will cause a parse error."

However 0777 is the default anyway, which gives the widest possible access, so you do not need to specify it, *unless* you want to set any later parameters (e.g. often it's useful to set the third option to **true** to enable creation of recursive directories, rather than creating an error if the parent doesn't exist.)